# Unable to run Django with docker-compose up command

Tags: mysql, django, docker

I am not able to run my Django and MySql application with `docker-compose up` command. I don't know how exactly to configure the host parameter of database from Django project settings. Earlier while configuring the same for other application it worked well. I don't understand what exactly went wrong this time.

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
     'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'eitan_database',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'mysql_db',
        'PORT': 3306,
    }
}
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  eitan-application:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py makemigrations
      && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db
  mysql_db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - "./mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
    ports:
      - "8080:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=eitan_database
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev gcc  -y
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app
```

**Stack Trace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
eitan-application_1  |   File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
eitan-application_1  |     main()
eitan-application_1  |   File "manage.py", line 17, in main
eitan-application_1  |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
eitan-application_1  |     utility.execute()
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
eitan-application_1  |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
eitan-application_1  |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in execute
eitan-application_1  |     self.check()
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 395, in check
eitan-application_1  |     include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 63, in _run_checks
eitan-application_1  |     issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
eitan-application_1  |     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
eitan-application_1  |     issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 9, in check
eitan-application_1  |     issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
eitan-application_1  |     with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
eitan-application_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 260, in cursor
eitan-application_1  |     return self._cursor()
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 236, in _cursor
eitan-application_1  |     self.ensure_connection()
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
eitan-application_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
eitan-application_1  |     self.connect()
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
eitan-application_1  |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
eitan-application_1  |     self.connect()
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
eitan-application_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
eitan-application_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
eitan-application_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 233, in get_new_connection
eitan-application_1  |     return Database.connect(**conn_params)
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
eitan-application_1  |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
eitan-application_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
eitan-application_1  |     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
eitan-application_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql_db' (-2)")
eitan_mysql_db_1 exited with code 2
```

**MySql Container Logs**

`docker-compose logs -f mysql_db`

```
Attaching to eitan_mysql_db_1
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:10+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.6.47-1debian9 started.
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.6.47-1debian9 started.
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.6.47) starting as process 1 ...
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysql_db_1           | mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
mysql_db_1           | InnoDB: No valid checkpoint found.
mysql_db_1           | InnoDB: If you are attempting downgrade from MySQL 5.7.9 or later,
mysql_db_1           | InnoDB: please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-downgrading.html
mysql_db_1           | InnoDB: If this error appears when you are creating an InnoDB database,
mysql_db_1           | InnoDB: the problem may be that during an earlier attempt you managed
mysql_db_1           | InnoDB: to create the InnoDB data files, but log file creation failed.
mysql_db_1           | InnoDB: If that is the case, please refer to
mysql_db_1           | InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-creating-innodb.html
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [ERROR] Aborting
mysql_db_1           | 
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Binlog end
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:11 1 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
mysql_db_1           | 
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.6.47-1debian9 started.
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.6.47-1debian9 started.
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.6.47) starting as process 1 ...
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysql_db_1           | mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
mysql_db_1           | InnoDB: No valid checkpoint found.
mysql_db_1           | InnoDB: If you are attempting downgrade from MySQL 5.7.9 or later,
mysql_db_1           | InnoDB: please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-downgrading.html
mysql_db_1           | InnoDB: If this error appears when you are creating an InnoDB database,
mysql_db_1           | InnoDB: the problem may be that during an earlier attempt you managed
mysql_db_1           | InnoDB: to create the InnoDB data files, but log file creation failed.
mysql_db_1           | InnoDB: If that is the case, please refer to
mysql_db_1           | InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-creating-innodb.html
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [ERROR] Aborting
mysql_db_1           | 
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Binlog end
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:14 1 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
mysql_db_1           | 
mysql_db_1           | 2020-03-03 10:10:17+00:00 [Note]
```

Comment: is your db container is up and running ? see what in docker ps

Comment: no the status of db container is Restarting (2) 6 second ago

Comment: then show the logs to see the errors: docker logs CONATINER_NAME

Comment: check `docker-compose logs -f mysql_db` for more info looks like your mysql container is not up

Comment: There is something wrong with your db try dropping it and restarting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `settings.py` the `HOST` parameter name was incorrect.

RUN
`docker ps`

Check for the `NAME` of image MySql:5.6 and copy it.

Then in your `setting.py` file update `HOST` parameter of your database with the `NAME` of newly create MySql container.

```
DATABASES = {
     'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'eitan_database',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '' c# name of newly created `mysql:5.6` image container name
        'PORT': 3306,
    }
}
```

Also, remove ports from service mysql_db which is in your `docker-compose` file.

```
ports:
      - "8080:3306"
```

Now RUN

`docker-compose up`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong with your setup

1. The error is a MySQL connection error because the service is not listening on port 3306 as you are binding it to port 8080 therefore you need to change your DATABASES dictionary to the following
2. Your python commands are in the wrong order. You need to run `makemigrations` prior to `migrate`.  The former creates the migration files, the latter then applies them to the database

Answer (score 1):

On your **docker-compose.yaml** file you are exposing the database on port **8080** and trying to access it through port **3306** on the **setting.py** file.